# stereocubes(12*1) is getting rendered as black screen using threejs + webVr

Tags: javascript, three.js, webvr, stereo-3d

I am trying to render 12x1 stereocube image strip using Three.js and want it to view in VR. But instead black screen is getting rendered every time without any error in console. basically I am extracting 12 images from the single stereocube image file using the function get TexturesFromAtlasFile , forming 2 meshes and passing to the scene. I am using a cube geometry. I am new to webVr and ThreeJs, please help. Code snippet used is given below:-

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/VRControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/effects/VREffect.js"></script>
<script>
  //Setup three.js WebGL renderer
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Append the canvas element created by the renderer to document body element.
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  // Create a three.js scene.
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  // Create a three.js camera.
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  //camera.layers.enable( 1 );
  // Apply VR headset positional data to camera.
  var controls = new THREE.VRControls(camera);
  // Apply VR stereo rendering to renderer.
  var effect = new THREE.VREffect(renderer);
  effect.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  //create a sphere - we'll use the inner surface to project our Mars image on to it
  var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100);
  var textures = this.getTexturesFromAtlasFile("img/san_miguel_vr_Samsung.png", 12);
  var materialArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: textures[i]
    }));
  }
  // create the mesh based on geometry and material
  //var mesh  = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialArray);
  var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialArray);
  //skybox.layers.set( 1 );
  scene.add(skybox);
  var materialsR = [];
  for (var i = 6; i < 12; i++) {
    materialsR.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: textures[i]
    }));
  }
  var skyBoxR = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialsR);
  //skyBoxR.layers.set( 2 );
  scene.add(skyBoxR);
  // Create a VR manager helper to enter and exit VR mode.
  var manager = new WebVRManager(renderer, effect, {
    hideButton: false
  });

  function animate(timestamp) {
    // Update VR headset position and apply to camera.
    controls.update();
    // Render the scene through the manager.
    manager.render(scene, camera, timestamp);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  // Kick off animation loop
  animate();

  function getTexturesFromAtlasFile(atlasImgUrl, tilesNum) {
    var textures = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tilesNum; i++) {
      textures[i] = new THREE.Texture();
    }
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
      var canvas, context;
      var tileWidth = imageObj.height;
      for (var i = 0; i < textures.length; i++) {
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = tileWidth;
        canvas.width = tileWidth;
        context.drawImage(imageObj, tileWidth * i, 0, tileWidth, tileWidth, 0, 0, tileWidth, tileWidth);
        textures[i].image = canvas
        textures[i].needsUpdate = true;
      }
    };
    imageObj.src = atlasImgUrl;
    return textures;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: just as a basic check : do you have any lighting ?

Comment: No, Since i am using MeshBasicMaterial so no lighting is defined.

Comment: [`WebVRManager`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webvr/WebVRManager.js) is undocumented, but if I'm reading the code correctly, you can just get one from [`renderer.vr`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/35ae830a7c4544582ed2759e5b18c5d6ef37c6d9/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L297). (three.js r93)

Comment: i was referencing borismus webvr template (https://github.com/borismus/webvr-boilerplate) where WebVRManager is used to  enter and exit VR mode. I will also try with renderer.vr